# How to extend OverridableComponent interface in Material-UI

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, styled-components

I'm trying to use `Container` component with styled-components using `ContainerProps` but then I can't pass `component` prop which belongs to `OverridableComponent` interface.
Code below gives me error which tells me that I can't pass `component` property. When I change `<Container/>` to `<MuiContainer/>` it works.

`MuiContainer` has type `OverridableComponent<ContainerTypeMap<{}, 'div'>>` but I can't import `OverridableComponent` from `@material-ui/core`

How can I make passing `component` property possible?

```
import { Container as MuiContainer, ContainerProps } from '@material-ui/core';
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Container = styled(MuiContainer)<ContainerProps>``;

export const Test = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Container maxWidth="lg" component="main">
        content
      </Container>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Is this still an issue? I've created a codesandbox with your code and it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

[Usage of component prop](https://next.material-ui.com/guides/typescript/#usage-of-component-prop)

```
const Container = styled(MuiContainer)<ContainerProps<'main', { component: 'main' }>>``;
```

[image: Edit component-prop]

Answer (score 1):

You can tell the Typescript compiler to retain the original `Container` prop types by asserting it:

```
import MuiContainer from "@mui/material/Container";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";

const Container = styled(MuiContainer)`
  background-color: pink;
  padding: 16px;
` as typeof MuiContainer;

export default function StyledComponents() {
  return (
    <Container maxWidth="lg" component="main">
      content
    </Container>
  );
}
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

### Reference

- https://mui.com/guides/composition/#with-typescript